# On roblox studio how do you make a script only activate after purchasing a developer product?

Tags: roblox

On roblox studio how do you make a script only activate after purchasing a developer product?

Answer (score 0):

The [MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/callback/MarketplaceService/ProcessReceipt) callback is called whenever a developer product purchase is completed. You should complete all the necessary steps to properly grant the product in the function set to this callback.

For example:

```lua
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local function processPurchase(purchaseInfo)
    -- Logic to handle purchase goes inside this function
    -- Return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted upon successful purchase
end

MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = processPurchase
```

Besides granting the product, you could also perform other actions or make other function calls inside the callback function.